# Strange Error Django Runtime

Tags: python, django, django-models, centos6

I have  VPS with CENTOS 6 Python 2.7 and Django 3.0 installed. I have created a new app and corrected my system path but every time I run server this is what I get

> RuntimeError: App registry isn't ready yet.

I do understand is already discussed in Django but information is very brief.

Can someone help me overcome this issue please.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: what django version again?

Comment: see http://django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/releases/1.7.html#app-loading-changes

Comment: I do apologise, Django 1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend that you use the latest Django release, (currently 1.6.1), instead of the development version.

Comment: I have now installed 1.6.1 and this is what I get on my new application when I run server File                "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.1-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 47, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting USE_I18N, but settings are not configured. You must either define the envi

Comment: If you're still stuck, please edit your question and include the complete traceback, instead of adding it as a comment.

Comment: Thank you, it has been resolved. It was all about version of python and django I was using, as Alasdair suggested.